# Admin Bar - Customizer Label Change

Tags: front-end, admin-bar, labels

I'm desperately trying to find out the best way to change the label "Customize" in the admin bar on the front end to "Customize Theme."  Have tried just about everything with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get_node](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_node) function and [admin_bar_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_bar_menu/) action. Like so,

```
function edit_customizer_node( $wp_admin_bar ) {
 $customize = $wp_admin_bar->get_node( 'customize' );
 if ( $customize ) {
  $customize->title = __( 'Customize Theme', 'text-domain' );
  $wp_admin_bar->remove_node( 'customize' );
  $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $customize );
 }
}
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'edit_customizer_node', 999 );
```

This can be placed in your theme's functions.php file.

This however moves the customizer link last on the admin bar. You need to do some reordering if you want to keep the link on it's original position.

p.s. You should replace the `text-domain` with your theme/plugin text-domain. You can use a plugin like [Loco Translate](https://fi.wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/) to translate your custom text domains, if needed.

Comment: ahhh, thanks so much!!!  think it's missing a closing bracket but I got that sorted out.  i really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Quite indeed, sorry about that. I added the missing closing bracket to my code example. You can mark my answer as accepted if you like, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers